# connecting to Ensembl via biopython

Tags: biopython

I have just join to the python and biopython work and like to  connect Ensebml and fetch some sequences and other data like TSS, list of some genes and etc. But my problem is that I cannot seem to find any method or module in biopython to do so. I know this is a very routin thing in perl using Ensembl API. 
I really appreciate if some tell me or point me to a document to see how these things are being done in biopython.
thanks

Comment: See https://github.com/biopython/biopython/issues/512

Answer (score 2):

There is [a similar question and a few answers](http://www.biostars.org/post/show/536/is-there-a-non-perl-alternative-to-accessing-ensembls-api/) in BioStar.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use and install the pyCogent module.  Then the specific bit to do with Ensembl is here: http://pycogent.org/examples/query_ensembl.html

Depending on what you want to do you may prefer to use the REST API from Ensembl which is here: http://beta.rest.ensembl.org